# ionic2 Property does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: json, ionic2

I am getting a json in typescript in ionic framework.
**The json is:**

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "user": {
        "loggedIn": true,
        "name": "Nulra",
        "password": ""
    }
}
```

And I print the data:

```
console.log("NULRA CHECKING: " + data.result + " " + data.user);
```

**It gives the error:**

```
Typescript Error

Property 'result' does not exist on type '{}'.

Property 'user' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

**auth-service.ts:**

```
login(credentials) {
    let opt: RequestOptions;
    let myHeaders: Headers = new Headers;

    myHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    myHeaders.append('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    opt = new RequestOptions({
        headers: myHeaders
    })

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(apiUrl+'login/0/login?email='+credentials.email+'&password='+credentials.password, opt)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            resolve(this.data);
        },(err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

**In login.ts:**

```
doLogin(){
    this.authService.login(this.loginData)
    .then(data => {
        console.log("NULRA CHECKING: " + data.result + " " + data.user);
    }
    .catch(err => {

    });
}
```

Anyone know how to deal with it? because the json I confirmed have result and user. Thanks a lot.

when console.log(data):
[image]

Comment: `console.log` just `data` in the `then`-function in `doLogin()` or in the `subscribe`, so that you can see what your working with.

Comment: in the dologin function.

Comment: what is output of - `console.log(data)`

Comment: Hi Swapnil,  i added the image above that console.log(data);

Comment: Just try it in your login.ts (authService.login().then)

let newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(newData.result);

Comment: Let me know if my solution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-

```
public userData: any = {};

doLogin(){
    this.authService.login(this.loginData)
    .then(data => {
        this.userData = data;
        console.log(`NULRA CHECKING: ${this.userData.result} ${this.userData.user}`);
    }
    .catch(err => {

    });
}
```

Comment: this is the better way, but you can also try `.then(data: object => {` in your previous code. Let me know if this also works.

Comment: Swapnil, use data: object cause error: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: Cool. Go with the answer's approach.

Comment: Thanks for your effort =)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got this solved when I simple called data['result'] instead of data.result;
For me it appeared only when i first executed ionic serve.